# How to join three tables to view scores?

Tags: php, mysql

i have 3 tables questions , scores and users.
questions table is something like this:

`q_id
q_text
option1
option2
option3
option4
answer_id`
in the above row answer_id means,  if answer_id value is 2 ,option2 is correct answer for question
user table is:

`user_id
user_name<br>password`.
.

Scores table is:

`user_id
q_id
answer_id`

in scores table scores are stored into following
urer_id=1;q_id=1,2,5,6;answer_id=2,4,3,1
my question is how to view each q_id of q_text + answer_id of option rows +  user name?

Comment: 1. See normalisation.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're trying to accomplish ?

```
SELECT answer.q_id, answer.answer_id,user.user_name 
FROM answer 
JOIN user ON user.user_id = answer.user_id
```